# Design of a multilingual site using episerver CMS

Tags: content-management-system, multilingual, episerver

How we one design an episerver site with multilaguage support using resource files?

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem using resource files in EPiServer, except for localizing the UI.

Any particular reason why the standard approach of XML language files don't fit your solution?